# The local variable may not have been initialized issue?

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a list without creating an array list, however, whenever I try to run the program I get the error "The local variable "letterGrade" may not have been initialized" I have tried changing the whole code but I still have the same problem >.< any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KifahProg4
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

String lastName,firstName,fullName,list;
int score,countA,countB,countC,countD,countF; //Student scores and number of Grades
int total = 0; //Student total score
double average; //Student Average score
char letterGrade; //Student grade
char response; //User continue y/n


do
{
  System.out.print("Enter the student last name: ");
  lastName = stdIn.next();
  System.out.print("Enter the student first name: ");
  firstName = stdIn.next();
  fullName = lastName + " " + firstName;
  for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
  { 
    System.out.print("Enter the score: ");
    score = stdIn.nextInt();
    total += score;
    average = (double) total/5;

    if(average >= 90 && average <=100)
    {
      letterGrade = 'A';
    }
    else if (average >=80)
    {
      letterGrade = 'B';  
    }
    else if (average >=70)
    {
      letterGrade = 'C';
    }
    else if (average >= 60)
    {
      letterGrade = 'D';
    }
    else if (average <= 59)
    {
      letterGrade = 'F';
    }
    System.out.println("Grade is: " );

    list = fullName + "\t" + total + average + "\t" + letterGrade + "\n";
  }
  System.out.println(
      "Would you like to add another student? (y/n): ");
  response = stdIn.next().charAt(0);   
} while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y');
```

} // end main
} // end class KifahProg4

Comment: I forgot to mention. I get the error on the (list = fullname + "\t" + total etc...) line

Comment: What if I put in a score of 101?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `letterGrade` to some default value before you use it to get rid of the compiler warning you're getting.

e.g.

```
char letterGrade = 'Z';
```

If it is still set to 'Z' when you get to `list = fullName + "\t" + total + average + "\t" + letterGrade + "\n";` you know you have an error condition...